# Difference between stored array and new array in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb.

I have the following data stored in mongodb

```
    { "_id" : ObjectId("4"), "uid" : "1", "friendsIds" : [ "2", "3" ] }
```

**Case 1:**
Now, I have new set of friendsIds  `["2","3","4"]`

I want to compare the both the sets, and get the value which is not stored in database. In this case, I want to get `4`

**Case 2:**
Now, I have new set of friendsIds  `["3","4"]`

I want to compare the both the sets, and get the value which is stored in database but not in the new set. In this case, I want to get `2`

Can the **Case 2** be done using mapReduce?

How to achieve both the cases in mongodb?

Answer (score 1):

For case 1, it looks like you need `[$addToSet][1]`. Take a look at the `$each` example.

For case 2, there is no such server-side function. Just bring back the document and compare client-side.

What action are you doing that you just want the `2` and not everything else?

Answer (score 0):

if you have two arrays

```
a = [ "2", "3" ]
b = ["2","3","4"]
```

in ruby :

```
a-b = ["4"]
```

Comment: I want to do it using mongodb query. In this case, I hope doing it in db should be much faster when compared to doing it in code.

Comment: One of the biggest mistakes developers often make is trying to offload processing to the database - let your app server handle that and let your database server handle inserting and querying.  Do the comparison in your app code.

Comment: @bryan Why do you say it as "biggest mistake"? What are all the drawbacks of offload processing to db? DB supposed to optimized for join operations right? [IMO, Case 2 can be solved as join operation]

Comment: I say that because database servers are often much more expensive and more difficult to scale than application servers are.  Trying to force the database to do more data processing than is necessary may sound easier, but ultimately means that your database server may begin spending more time processing data than fetching and inserting it.  Facebook specifically mentioned this in one of their engineering blog entries.

Comment: Plus, MongoDB doesn't do joins.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the aggregation framework using its [set operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#set-operators):

```
> db.foo.insert({"friendsIds" : [ "2", "3"]})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {diff: {$setDifference: [["2","3","4"], '$friendsIds']}}} ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53490a53a0e3abbe0dd0c21c"), "diff" : [ "4" ] }

> db.foo.aggregate([ {$project: {diff: {$setDifference: ['$friendsIds', ["3","4"]]}}} ])
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53490a53a0e3abbe0dd0c21c"), "diff" : [ "2" ] }
```